# Disable or Replace Some HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a online webpage. There has a code placed by default:-

```
<body><center><table border="0" width="100%"><tr><td valign="top" align="center"><div class="webpage_body" style="text-align: left;">
```

I am facing many issues with this code. It is placed after `</head>` tag. I want to disable or replace it via JavaScript or CSS.
I've tried to replace it into an unknown HTML by javascript:-

```
var s="<center><table border="0" width="100%"><tr><td valign="top" align="center"><div class="webpage_body" style="text-align: left;">"; s = s.replace(/<center>/g, "<c>"); s = s.replace(/<table>/g,"<ta>"); s = s.replace(/<tr>/g,"<fr>"); alert(s);
```

But nothing happens to it. (**Edit:**) Also I can't replace the `<table` because it isn't `<table>`! How can I do this?

Comment: Your simply defining a string and changing it's value, that will not affect the DOM. What's the issue with the default HTML and why can't you change it rather than trying to fix it by *"hacking"* in *"correct"* HTML?

Comment: You should wrap your `s = "htmlcode";` with `'` not with `"`. This should do it.

Comment: Let me allow to check @Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in there. You're using `"` for the `HTML` string but inside of the `HTML`, you use `"` too. That will break it. Just try to use `'` at the beginning and the end of the string.

---

This is how it looks if you are using a editor:
[image: String with "]

This if how it looks if you are wrap it with `'` instead of `"`
[image: String with ' instead of "]

*The Boxes are there to visualize the strings.*

---

Here's the working example:

```js
var s = '<center><table border="0" width="100%"><tr><td valign="top" align="center"><div class="webpage_body" style="text-align: left;">';
s = s.replace(/<center>/g, "<c>");
s = s.replace(/<table>/g, "<ta>");
s = s.replace(/<tr>/g, "<fr>");
alert(s);
```

Just a little hint: In your example, `<table>` will never be replaced because your example has no `<table>`. Only `<table`.

You can do this with `s.replace(/<table/g, "<ta");` or `s.replace(/table/g, "ta");`.

Comment: Oh OK! How can I replace the `<table` for now? Is there any way?

Comment: Just do `s.replace(/<table/g, "<ta");` or `s.replace(/table/g, "ta");`

Comment: @user8536056 I've added some images to show you the mistake.